# Beamer - Use custom environment on TOC frames

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, header-footer, environments

I defined a environment `slide` based on frame to get rules beneath the headline and above the footer and get the section in the frametitle.

```
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\insertsection}}\\#1\\\vspace*{-.38cm}\rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}}\vspace*{-.5cm}}
{\hfill\hspace*{-.8cm}\vspace*-.8cm}\color{itemizecolor}\rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}
\end{frame}}
```

I would now like to use this style on the TOC frames as well. Is there a way to tell latex to use this environment for TOC?

EDIT: On request, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\definecolor{itemizecolor}{rgb}{0.18,0.22,0.60}
\newenvironment{slide}[1]
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\insertsection}}\\#1\\\vspace*{-.38cm}\rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}}\vspace*{-.5cm}}
{\vfill\hspace*{-.8cm}\color{itemizecolor}\rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}
 \end{frame}}

 \begin{document}

%----------- titlepage ----------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%----------- slide --------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}{Inhalt}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section}


\begin{slide}{slide title}
Test
Test

\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Supplied an MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some time I got it all working, here is a fully worked example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll} % needed to push line to the bottom of the page

\newenvironment{slide} % wrapper for frame, wrting Section \\ Subsection in the header, adding lines below header and above footer
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
\frametitle{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\insertsection}}\\\insertsubsection\\\vspace*{-.38cm}\rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}}}
{\btVFill\hspace*{-.8cm}\color{itemizecolor}\rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}
 \end{frame}}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{myframe number} % moving the frame numbers up a bit, too close to bottom by default
{
  \hfill
  \usebeamercolor[itemizecolor]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}
  \raisebox{-0.3cm}[0cm][.5cm]{% <--- change here
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\hspace*{.3cm}}%
}

% some fumbling with the itemize symbols in toc etc., and genereal appereance - not strictly relevant for the problem, but maybe usefull for someone.

\definecolor{itemizecolor}{rgb}{0.18,0.22,0.60}
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{square unnumbered}{%
  \leavevmode\leftskip=1.75ex%
  \llap{{\color{itemizecolor}$\blacksquare$}}%
  \kern1.5ex\inserttocsection\par}
\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{square unnumbered}{%
  \leavevmode\leftskip=4.6ex%
  \llap{{\color{itemizecolor}$\blacksquare$}}%
  \kern1.5ex\inserttocsubsection\par}

\usetheme{default} 
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[none] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{itemizecolor}$\blacksquare$}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square unnumbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[square unnumbered]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[myframe number]
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=Black}


% presentation boddy

\title{Interesting Topic}
\author{Ano Nym}

\begin{document}

% modified toc at start of each section
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\subsection*{Overview}
\begin{slide}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{slide}
}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Table of Contents}
\subsection*{ }
\begin{slide}
\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=hide]
\end{slide}


\section{Section1}
\subsection{subsec 1}
\begin{slide}
abc
\end{slide}
\subsection{subsec 2}
\begin{slide}
abc
\end{slide}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{subsec 1}
\begin{slide}
abc
\end{slide}
\subsection{subsec 2}
\begin{slide}
abc
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Titlepage]

[image: Table of Contents]

[image: Reduced TOC before section]

[image: Content Slide example]

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something or why not simply write

```
\begin{slide}{Inhalt}
    \tableofcontents
\end{slide}
```

---

That said, I myself would not define a custom environment as wrapper for a frame, because in my personal experience, this causes more problems than it solves. Why not using beamers own mechanism to modify the frametitle and place a line in the footer?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{itemizecolor}{rgb}{0.18,0.22,0.60}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\insertsection}}\\%
    \insertframetitle \\%
    \vspace*{-.38cm}%
    \rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}%
    \vspace*{-.5cm}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \rule{1.12\textwidth}{0.08ex}%
    \vspace*{0.2cm}
}

\begin{document}

%----------- titlepage ----------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%----------- slide --------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}{Inhalt}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}{slide title}
    Test
    Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like a good approach to me, but it has stil some problems for me:
1: The header is indented. In my version, the header starts directly at the left, without the extra space.
2: The lines go completly to the right end of the frame. I would like them  to have a symmetrical distance on both sides.
3: When I try to add frame numbers, they appear on the left instead of the right, sometimes the line is not plottet at all.... I wasn't able to figure out why exactly what happens.
I have figured out a solution based on my attempt and will post it below soon.

Comment: Oh and I totally forgot: Thanks for the tip with \begin{slide}{Inhalt}
    \tableofcontents
\end{slide}. That solved my original issue perfectly.